# Can't get message delivery receipt in XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am new to XMPP. I'm using XMPP and Open fire server for my chat app. The application is working but now I want  to get message delivery receipt. I'm using the following code for that,
 in `setupStream`:

```
   xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
   xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
   [xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:xmppStream];
```

And in `sendMessage`:

```
    NSString *messageID=[xmppStream generateUUID];
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:messageID];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:myJID];
    [message addChild:body];
```

But i can't get message delivery receipt. How can I get it? Anybody knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already receiving delivery receipt responses, but `XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts` module does not handle it automatically. You need to store all incoming and outgoing messages (check `XMPPMessageArchiving` module, it can save messages in the `XMPPMessageArchiving_CoreDataStorage` instance), check if message `hasReceiptResponse` (defined in `XMPPMessage+XEP_0184` category), find the message id in the receipt response and mark corresponding message as "delivered" in the message storage (you may need to add new property e.g. "delivered" to `XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataObject` if you will use this module, or make your own storage mechanism)

Comment: I am getting this: SEND: <message from="sender@localhost" id="16E0CCBE-C906-4D10-ADB4-74C9AB340106" type="chat" to="receiver@localhost"><body>4588</body><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/></message>

Comment: @DhvlGolakiya recipient must support XEP-0184 too

Comment: Hey @vitalyster XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject there is no  hasReceiptResponse method it's Method of  XMPPMessage so where to request receipt and where to Check whether that message is delivered or not