# Message send and received status using xmpp (Jabberd) ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

**I want to show status of sent and received message for chat message.
I found the below code, but i am not understating how to use it and where i will receive response for particular message status.**

```
XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts* xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts  alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
```

[xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:self.xmppStream];

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25899347/1097384

Comment: @ vitalyster i am using but not getting exactlly how to handle with database.. please share code which is helpfull for me thanks...

Comment: How can i save and check which message is sent or not for online and offline sent status.?